# How do I download Ubuntu One files to my new computer?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I need to know how to down load all my sync'ed folders from ubuntu one to my new computer..

Answer (score 1):

Install/configure UbuntuOne and login to your account, your selected files/folders should start synchronizing automatically from the servers to your new computer.

For more information on how to setup UbuntuOne on different Ubuntu releases please refer to [the official wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Setup) guide.

If you are running Ubuntu 11.04 or 11.10 [this simple illustrated guide](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-ubuntu-one/) will aid you on setting your account. After this is done you need to way a bit before all your files are downloaded from the server, the process time will change according to the amount of files you need to synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

Start Ubuntu One from the Launcher or from the Dash. Once there, sign in ("I already have an account!") and then on the Cloud Folders tab, tick the folders you want synced with this machine. (Cloud folders are not automatically synced to every machine, because you might not want them all to be if your machine is short of disc space or you only want certain folders on a particular computer.)

Answer (score -1):

As its now in sunset mode, the synch still tries upload too, which it cant do, obviously that paging to upload is a conflict.  Download synch may take quite a while

Comment: This doesn't seem to be fully researched or completely accurate. source: https://one.ubuntu.com/services/shutdown/